# How to quickly setup Spark on YARN in a cluster with a bash script?

Tags: bash, hadoop, apache-spark, installation

During my self paced learing of Hadoop and Spark, I found very tedious the environment setup phase during which we need to setup a small cluster and repeat installation and configuration for all dependencies on all nodes. Java, Hadood, Spark. Is there a way to get this done using a bash script?

Comment: Prerequisites: Hadoop group and user are created on all nodes. SSH is configured to access all slaves from the master. DNS resulution is setup on all nodes (hosts file -  maybe this could be added to the script ;)

Answer (score 0):

I took a first stab at it and bash can definitively do the job. Once SSH is properly setup for the cluster, a bash script like the following is a good start. It needs some refinement but still ... The sample script bellow only  takes Hadoop/Yarn into account for now but this is a work in progress. Same approach can be used to setup Java and Spark on all nodes. I will update this answer when I will have it completed ;)

```
!/bin/bash
for x in hadoop-slave1 hadoop-slave2 hadoop-slave3
 do
    ssh $x  bash -c "' 

    cd ~
    wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.7.3/hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
    ln -s hadoop-2.7.3 hadoop
    echo "# HADOOP" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/hduser/hadoop" >> ~/.bashrc 
    source ~/.bashrc
    echo "export HADOOP_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX" >> ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc

    mkdir -p ~/tmp   #create tmp dir used and configured in hadoop
    # work around an issue I got with JAVA_HOME env var beeing lost.
    echo export `env | grep ^JAVA_HOME` >> ~/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

    exit

    '"
    # copy config files to slaves. assuming that master is already setup - to be improved
    scp ~/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml hduser@$x:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop
    scp ~/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml hduser@$x:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop
    scp ~/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml hduser@$x:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop

done
```

Comment: Or you could use Ambari automated installation